# scan a specific area of pixels

Tags: c#, colors, pixel, scanning

i want to check if a pixel, in a certain area, has a certain color.
Currently i can only check the middle of my Screen. But i realized that i would rather scan a 10x10 box from the mid of my screen.

This is my code  i am actually using at the moment.

```
Point xy = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 2 + 1, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 2 + 1);

Color GetPixel(Point position)
        {
            using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1))
            {
                using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    graphics.CopyFromScreen(position, new Point(0, 0), new Size(1, 1));
                }
                return bitmap.GetPixel(0, 0);
            }
        }

color = GetPixel(xy);
Color purple = Color.FromArgb(255,254,93,255);

 if (color.Equals(purple) == true).....
```

Is there a option of scanning a box from 10x10 for the color purple and return true when the color is in this box?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function:

```
private bool ContainsColor(Point StartPosition, int BoxSize, Color ColorToScanFor)
    {
        using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap(BoxSize, BoxSize))
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
            {
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(StartPosition, Point.Empty, new Size(BoxSize, BoxSize));

                for (int X = 0; X < image.Width; X++)
                {
                    for (int Y = 0; Y < image.Height; Y++)
                    {
                        if (image.GetPixel(X, Y).ToArgb() == ColorToScanFor.ToArgb())
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And when you want to call the function try something like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(ContainsColor(new Point(0, 0), 10, Color.Black).ToString());
```